# Global property is not getting added when saving it from groovy script using "launch test runner"

Tags: groovy, soapui

1. Step 1 : I have a soap rest project, In that i am getting a userID from response.
2. Step 2 : When i run the test case separately to get the userID, the groovy script for setting the user ID in global property is working fine. 
   Refer : `com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpansionUtils.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('userID', 'ID from response')`
3. Step 3 : But when i run my whole project using "launch test runner" to get the userID from response and setting the userID to a global property as defined in the above example is not working.

Does any one have idea on this?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Can you please provide full script? Do you mean to say that it is not setting value to global property? Are you sure if the value is part of the response of step1 and is retrieved correctly?

Comment: Yes. Am sure the value is part of response. Even if i hardcode the value and set the value as global property, it is not working. Yes it is not setting the value to global property if I run the whole project with test runner. But the global property is set when i run the test case alone but not the full project. Thanks

Comment: Here in the link you can see the project structure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570269/how-to-pass-parameter-from-one-project-to-another-project

Comment: Ok, now the question is that how to set a value for a global property, is that right? And did you try getting the property value after setting it?

Comment: Yes you are right. Set the value to global property using groovy script when running the project using test runnner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the groovy script which can set the global property value.

Groovy Script

```groovy
def newValue = 'testsetvalue'
//set the value to global property called PROPERTY_NAME
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', newValue)
// get the property value which was set above.
def getNewValue = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME')
//assert it
assert getNewValue == newValue
```

Comment: This is not working when I run the project using test runner. but this works fine if we run individual test case using run button.

Comment: Please recheck, there was a typo in the last line (missed `t` in assert). Second thing is you might run using launch test runner without saving the project. Make sure the project is saved before running using testrunner. Let me know once you follow the above.