# How to pass parameter from one project to another project?

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am having 4 Rest API’s Projects as of attached screen shot.

I Need to pass a generated userID from project 1 (1_Admin Basics & Get APIs) to other project (2_Courses & Classes).

I am running each project by using test runner.  Global property transfer is not working in this scenario. Can some 1 help me out to do the above mentioned scenario.

I don’t want to combine 4 projects into 1 project. It should be 4 projects and need to pass the parameter from 1 project to other.

[image]

Comment: What is the use case? I believe it is not general practice sharing variables across the projects. If there is any constant which is needed for multiple projects (assuming that no project mutating the property value), then use global properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it for example using the [`workspace`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/workspace/Workspace.html) property to access the other projects from the current one to get the properties from its. You can do it through a *groovy script*.

In the first project add a *groovy script testStep* in your *testCase* and set the property at *project level* as follows:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('myProp','myValue')
```

In the second project add another *groovy script* in the *testCase* to get the value of your property through the `workspace` and assign at your desired level (for example in a *testSuite*, but you can add wherever you need it):

```
// get the other project
def otherProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName('SecondProjectName')
// get your property value
def value = otherProject.getPropertyValue('myProp')
log.info value
// set the var at some level in this case in testSuite
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('varFromOtherProject',value)
```

Then use the variable in the *testStep* of your second project using the follow notation:

`${#TestSuite#varFromOtherProject}`

**UPDATE:**

Seems that you're running your projects alone using *testRunner* therefore you can't access other projects using `workspace`, so as a possible workaround you can write your property value in a *File* in your first project and then read the *File* content in your second project.

So in your *first project* add a *groovy script testStep* with the follow code:

```
new File('./myProp').text = 'someValue'
```

Then in your *second project* read the *File* and set the property at some test level:

```
// get the value from the file
def value = new File('./myProp').text
log.info value
// set the var at some level in this case in testSuite
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('varFromOtherProject',value)
```

And as it's explained before use the follow notation in your *SOAP testStep* to get the property:

`${#TestSuite#varFromOtherProject}`

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Here  the problem is, when i run the project with "test runner" testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('myProp','myValue') this is not working. Property is not added in the project property. You have any idea on this ? But if i run the testcase alone, I can see this property is added to the project level.

Comment: @user3511026 the problem is that you're running each project in standalone mode using testRunner... so there is no common workspace for theirs... I check it out.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what should be done to fix this ? Answer will be very helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: @user3511026 I add a possible workaround writing the content of your property on a file... take a look on it `:)`

Comment: Can u also look into this ?  Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595789/how-to-run-multiple-projects-at-a-single-launch